# виртуальная машина не реагирует на сигнал завершения работы

Tags: virtualbox, виртуальная-машина

Установила виртуальную машину (linux mint) в VirtualBox через импорт конфигураций. Запускается, работает хорошо, но когда хочу выйти и пытаюсь подать сигнал о завершении работы, она не реагирует. С чем это может быть связано? Объясните, пожалуйста.